# Javascript Unit testing and refactoring (using Angular js framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I (as a js/ng newbie) wanna know how do I start on my unit-test journey for the following angular code (Controller with some functions) and mocking necessary? Basically, I want to test extracted() function. Would appreciate beautiful suggestions. Thanks

```
    angular.module('HelloWorld')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, firstService, secondService, messageService) {

    'use strict';

    function goWhereTheWindBlows() { // some implementation }

    $scope.mainFun = function(var1) {

        firstService.showSomething(var1, function() {
            var result = secondService.read(var1); 
            // result is the result of http get (200 or 400)
            extracted(result);
        }, goWhereTheWindBlows);

        function extracted(result) {
            result.then(function () {
                messageService.addMessage({ message: 'Success', type: 'standard' });
            }, function () {
                messageService.addMessage({ message: 'Failure', type: 'error' });
            });
        }
    };
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **grunt-karma** to perform unit tests. 
You should have tests folder in your structure. 
Write unit test for this code in **jasmine** syntax. 
use **beforeEach** to use **module** in which your controller is. 
create variable and assign controller to it using **$controller** function. 
Take variable with controller and run **expect** on your method in it function. 
Thats it, run **grunt test** and see the results.

[Some explantation](http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/use-karma-and-grunt-to-run-your-jasmine-tests-in-real-time/) about writing in jasmine syntax.

For mocking http data - that one used with **$http** service, use **$httpBackend** service in angular-mocks.js. 
This is fake backend in which you write for example get requests, and specify answers from this using **whenGET()** and **expect**. There are also other requests like POST, PUT. Basically after defining result expectation you use **$httpBackend.flush()** method to flush changes, so your would retrieve data.

There are also end to end tests, which you can perform with **protractor** using **selenium webdriver**, but these are hard to integrate with grunt test, so you may run all tests as two commands.

Note that end to end tests are not in jasmine syntax, so you write them different.

Comment: Right, very useful answer. How would you mock the result the comes back from http request, that is                                    {code} var result = secondService.read(var1); 
            // result is the result of http get (200 or 400)
            extracted(result); {code}